# Code Generation for All CLR supported language using a CodeDomSerializer

Tags: c#, user-controls, codedom

I am implementing Code Generation for WindowsForm control at Design-Time, using a Custom CodeDomSerializer.

Here is what I have.

- A user control i.e. MyControl written
  in C#.
- MyControl has a property
  MyControlProperty of type ObjectXXX
  that is accessible publicly.(like
  myControl.MyControlProperty).
- The type ObjectYYY has a public property
  PropertyXXX of type Collection.
- The ObjectXXX has a internal field of type ObjectYYY.
- The ObjectXXX should be initialized by passing Collection (which
  is nothing but ObjectYYY.PropertyXXX).

The code generated should be as given in the code snippet below.

```
Line1. NamespaceX.NamespaceY.ObjectXXX x = new NamespaceX.NamespaceY.ObjectXXX(NamespaceX.NamespaceY.ObjectYYY.PropertyXXX);
Line2. myControl.MyControlProperty = x;
```

I succeeded in generating the aforementioned code at Design-Time by writing a custom CodeDomSerializer FOR C# Language.

But, if i use MyControl for developing an application in C++ Language, the DOT operator is serialized for both ScopeResolution and Pointer-To-Member operator.

What I am doing for code in Line1 is,

```
string fullyQualifiedName = "NamespaceX.NamespaceY.ObjectYYY.PropertyXXX"; // HERE VARIABLE NAME IS HARDCODED WITH TWO TYPES OF OPERATORS
CodeExpression[] parameters = new CodeExpression[] {new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(fullyQualifiedName);};
CodeStatement code = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(typeof(ObjectXXX), "objectXXX1", new CodeObjectCreateExpression(new CodeTypeReference(typeof(ObjectXXX)), parameters));
generatedCode.Add(code); //generatedCode has the final code
```

For Line2,

```
CodeExpression codeLhs = new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(myControlVariable + "." + "MyControlProperty"); // HERE Pointer-To-Member IS HARDCODED AS DOT
CodeExpression codeRhs = new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("objectXXX1");
CodeAssignStatement codeAssignStmt = new CodeAssignStatement(codeLhs, codeRhs);
generatedCode.Add(codeAssignStmt); //generatedCode has the final code
```

Obviously the C++ Designer generated code should have '::' operator(and not DOT) for the ScopeResolution and '->' for the Pointer-To-Member resolution. I was not able to figure out how to make the code serialization for any CLR supported language.

How to solve this problem?

-Thanks a bunch

Dattebayo

Comment: Note that the CodeDomSerializer api working on the DOM (ass opposed to raw test) is rather defunct these days since it has not been adequately updated to support the additions to c# 3.0 syntax and has no serious support at all in the less common CLR languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the quick reply.

I found the solution.

What i need was generating code containing property access and generating code for of .NET types.

To generate code that accesses a property, one should use CodePropertyReferenceExpression. This solves my problem with Line2.

To generate code that contains a Type, one should use Code CodeTypeReferenceExpression.
This combined with CodePropertyReferenceExpression solved problem with Line1.

Now, I am able to generate code properly w.r.t. the Language in use.

```
//For C# The code would be
NamespaceX.NamespaceY.ObjectXXX x = new NamespaceX.NamespaceY.ObjectXXX(NamespaceX.NamespaceY.ObjectYYY.PropertyXXX);
this.myControl.MyControlProperty = x;

//For C++ The code would be
NamespaceX::NamespaceY::ObjectXXX x = new NamespaceX::NamespaceY::ObjectXXX(NamespaceX::NamespaceY::ObjectYYY::PropertyXXX);
this->myControl->MyControlProperty = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but have you looked at [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx) its a multi language code generator written in .Net. It doesn't use CodeDomSerializer, but it does generate good code - maybe it'll solve your underlying problem without having to re-invent the wheel?